# How to check which SSIS package updates my table?

Tags: sql, ssis

I am troubleshooting some missing QlikView data.
My setup is:

> Source ERP -> ODBC + SSIS -> SQL Tables -> SQL Views  -> qvw creating qvd's -> loading qvd`s -> front end design

There is some data missing front end so reverse engineering it I got to SQL table, which has data missing.

How do I know which SSIS package is updating this data?
And how do I find it?